# How to get array indexes of three smaller values?

Tags: arrays

I have an array that represents distances, so I try to get an array with the indexes from the 3 smaller and increasing distances, this way:

```
array([[   2.8],
       [ 206. ],
       [  84.4],
       [ 297.6],
       [ 112.7],
       [ 235.4],
       [ 170.7],
       [  22.2],
       [ 264.1],
       [ 163.2],
       [  43.7],
       [ 131.2]])
Result = [0, 7, 10]
```

Any idea o suggestion? Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/k-largestor-smallest-elements-in-an-array/

Answer (score 0):

I found a not very elegant but working approach. If someone has another fast or better version, will be welcome.

```
from operator import itemgetter
# b distances array
b = [i for i in enumerate(b)]
b = sorted(b, key=itemgetter(1))
b = [i[0] for i in b]
result = b[:3]
result
# [0,7,10]
```